# Rails Active Record Query Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Have two model, Rooms and Services.

```
Rooms ->  has_many :services, dependent: :destroy
```

```
Services -> belongs_to :rooms
```

In controller, I need to customize the JSON. So I haven't using serializer here.

```
@room_services = @room.services
```

As per my JSON based on condition I need to get service value

// I have lot of conditions before each, so that I haven't added serializer.

```
@room_services.each do |value|

 data.push({ name: value.name, is_active: value.is_active })

end
```

While running this, I can able to see the query n number of times. But I have already stored the activerecord value in **@room_services**.

Someone please help me to understand the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Well I see a couple of problems.

First, your model names should be singular, e.g. `Room` not `Rooms`. And in service.rb, it should be `belongs_to :room`.

Now answering your question, ActiveRecord does 'lazy_loading`, meaning it formats a query, but doesn't execute until the moment the result is needed.

It looks as if you're trying to populate a `data` array.

Try this:

```rb
@room.services.collect{|s| {name: s.name, is_active: s.is_active}}
```

However if you're trying to form a JSON string, Rails can help:

```rb
@room.services.to_json

# in service.rb

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options={})
    super(only: [:name, :is_active])
  end
end
```

I'm assuming here that `name` and `is_active` are attributes on the `Service` model.